# React Hook "useState" is called in function "handleFormSubmit" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this React form which I want to submit:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const FooterOne = ({ footerLight }) => {

  const handleFormSubmit = async (formValues) => {
    const { email } = formValues;
    const [response, setResponse] = useState("");

    const body = {
      email,
    };

    try {
      const result = await fetch(
          `https://.....lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/`,
          {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
          }
      );

      const response = await result.text();
      setResponse(response);
    } catch (error) {
      // Print error
    }
  };

  return (
    <>        
      <form className='newsletter-form position-relative d-block d-lg-flex d-md-flex' onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} >
        <input
            type='text'
            className='input-newsletter form-control me-2'
            placeholder='Enter your email'
            name='email'
            required=''
            autoComplete='off'
            value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <input
            type='submit'
            value='Subscribe'
            data-wait='Please wait...'
            className='btn btn-primary mt-3 mt-lg-0 mt-md-0'
        />
      </form>                    
    </>
  );
};

export default FooterOne;
```

I get error:

```
Line 8:37:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "handleFormSubmit" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

How I can submit the form with minimum HTML code change?

Comment: What's unclear from the error? That function is indeed not a component or a hook, so either you need to refactor it into a hook or move the state out into the component (neither of which necessarily changes the HTML). Also note there's no point writing a fragment with only one child.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware how to implement this. Can you show me how to implement this properly, please?

Comment: How to implement what, exactly? If you mean refactoring it into a hook, then start by researching e.g. _"react custom hook"_. Moving the state is in the first instance just a matter of moving the _line_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments and in the error message, the `useState` hook inside the `handleFormSubmit` function is not allowed. The hook should be used in a React functional component and not in a regular JavaScript function.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const FooterOne = ({ footerLight }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [submitButtonLabel, setSubmitButtonLabel] = useState('Subscribe');

  const handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const body = {
      email,
    };

    try {
      setSubmitButtonLabel('Please wait...');

      const requestPromise = axios.post(
        'https://.....lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/',
        body,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }
      );

      requestPromise.then(() => {
          setSubmitButtonLabel('Subscribe');
          setEmail('');
      }).catch((error) => {
        // Handle error
        console.error('Error submitting form:', error);
      });


    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
      console.error('Error submitting form:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form
        className='newsletter-form position-relative d-block d-lg-flex d-md-flex'
        onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
      >
        <input
          type='text'
          className='input-newsletter form-control me-2'
          placeholder='Enter your email'
          name='email'
          required=''
          autoComplete='off'
          value={email}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          type='submit'
          value={submitButtonLabel}
          className='btn btn-primary mt-3 mt-lg-0 mt-md-0'
        />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default FooterOne;
```

Comment: Thanks, I can submit the form properly but I have one more question: How I can clear the form input when the button is pressed?

Comment: After your `setResponse(response);` clear it like so: `setEmail('');`

Comment: Thanks, I see one bug: `data-wait='Please wait...'` is not working. maybe it's not activated during form submit?

Comment: Oh, did not notice it. I've never seen that, what is your intention with it?

Comment: I want to when I click the button `Subscribe` to update the label to `Please wait...` during the POST call and return back the old button label.

Comment: @PeterPenzov see edited answer. Added a `submitButtonLabel` hook.

Comment: Thanks, last question: Looks like I get slow server response time. Is it possible to make a async call using axios? I don't need to wait response message from the server? Just a quick POST.

Comment: See edited, I think that is what you are after.

Comment: With latest code I get: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at '...........us-east-1.on.aws/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.` Any idea why after the latest update I get this issue?

Comment: @PeterPenzov It means you haven't configured CORS in your backend. If you are using express then you can search `cors` package on npm.